# fltk1.3 sometimes adds custom widgets

Tags: c++, fltk

My Fl_Window is not automatically adding my custom made Fl_Widget...but only sometimes. Here is how it works:

Fl_Window will automatically add this Fl_Widget:

```
//Menu version 1
class Menu : public Fl_Menu_Bar
{
public:
    Menu(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char* l=0)
        : Fl_Menu_Bar(x, y, w, h, l) {}
//...
};
//...
```

Fl_Window will **not** automatically add this Fl_Widget:

```
//Menu version 2
class Menu : public Fl_Menu_Bar
{
public:
    Menu()
        : Fl_Menu_Bar(0,0,800,30) {}
//...
};
//...
```

Here is how I am running it:

**version 1**

```
//main
Fl_Window win(800,600);

//This will be added automatically
Menu m1(0,0,800,30);

win.show();
win.end();

return Fl::run();
//...
```

**version 2**

```
//main
Fl_Window win(800,600);

//This will not be added automatically.
Menu m2();

win.show();
win.end();

return Fl::run();
//...
```

To compile (I'm using ubuntu), I use

```
g++ main.cpp Menu.cpp -lfltk -lfltk_images
```

Why is version 1 of my Menu automatically added to *win*, but not version 2? Particularly, how can I have my class objects added to an Fl_Window regardless of how its constructor looks?

The [documentation](http://fltk.org/doc-1.3/subclassing.html#subclassing_subclassing) makes some mention of this, but it seems like the difference is only relavent when using FLUID (which I'm not).

Answer (score 0):

Your second menu is hidden the first one.

```
m1              -> x = 0, y = 0, w = 800, h = 30
m2 (by default) -> x = 0, y = 0, w = 800, h = 30
```

Both have same values.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what my actual code looks like. I was doing one at a time, but I put them together to be concise here. I will change the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember this as some special C++ behavior: if you use the default constructor, don't specify the parentheses in the variable declaration (since that has some special meaning), in other words, instead of:

```
Menu m2();
```

Just write:

```
Menu m2;
```